# How to Reduce the size of big structure in CPP

Tags: c++

Ex:

```
typedef struct emp_t {
   private :
   uint8_t highestEmpData {INVALID_OPTION}; // INVALID_OPTION = 0xff;
   std::array<std::salary<bool>, MAX_NUM_OF_ACTIVE_EMP> salaryToTransmit {}; 
   //MAX_NUM_OF_ACTIVE_EMP = 11;
   std::array<std::salary,<uint32_t>, MAX_NUM_OF_EMP> amountOfDataAvailablePerEmp{}; 
   //MAX_NUM_OF_EMP = 8; 
   std::array<EventsList, MAX_NUM_OF_ACTIVE_EMP> aBuffer {};
   std::array<EventsList, MAX_NUM_OF_ACTIVE_EMP> bBuffer {};
   std::array<UlRbContext_t, MAX_NUM_OF_ACTIVE_EMP> rbCon {};
   std::array<Lc_t, MAX_NUM_OF_EMP>PriorityList {};  
   uint8_t availableBs {MAX_NUM_OF_BS}; // MAX_NUM_OF_BS = 8;
   uint8_t availableSr {MAX_NUM_OF_SR}; // MAX_NUM_OF_SR =3;
} emp_t;

main() {
   emp_t empl[MAX_NUM_OF_EMP]; // here MAX_NUM_OF_EMP = 180;
}
```

I want to change `MAX_NUM_OF_EMP = 1000` but here issue is `emp_t` size
will be huge so how can I reduce the size of `emp_t`? Ex: for
`MAX_NUM_OF_EMP =180` size is 180 * emp_t size (around 500kb). if i
changed it with 1000 then size become 1000 * 500kb  = huge size .

Comment: Declare it as a global variable instead of local, then the size shouldn't be much of a problem.

Comment: Does every single `emp_t` instance need its own copy of the `amountOfDataAvailablePerEmp` array? Maybe it should be a `static` class variable. (Similarly for `salaryToTransmit`, `aBuffer`, `bBuffer`, etc., where it's not at all clear why each `emp_t` needs its own unique copy telling it about all the others.)

Comment: How did you compute `emp_t` size? At first sight 500kb seems a lot (but we don't know as some type are not defined in the question).

Answer (score 0):

> how i can reduce the size of emp_t ?

Using indirection. Instead of storing the large arrays as a members directly, you can allocate them dynamically, and store  pointers that refer to them indirectly. Or even better, use `std::vector` which takes care of memory management. This design has an even better benefit: The number of elements in the vector doesn't need to be constant.

You must also avoid large automatic variables, so you should allocate dynamically the array `empl`. `std::vector` will be useful in this case as well.